# How to simplify the sentence and keep the same meaning?

Tags: abbreviations, esl

I want to say

> Riding Uber is similar to going to the barber shop,
>   Tip is not mandatory but always welcome.

How I can shorten it?

Comment: That Questions seems to be as much about writing style as the language itself, which means it really belongs on a site dealing with writing style.

Since you're here "Riding Uber is similar to going to the barber('s) shop." After the full stop, either "*A tip*" or "*Tipping*" is not mandatory. "…always welcome" suggests *to the tipper* rather than the driver. Try "*will*" always "*be"* welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Like your barber, Uber drivers appreciate a tip.

or more direct

After a snip, you tip ?
Appreciated your trip ?

Answer (score 0):

Like at the barber, you don't have to tip Uber drivers, but it's nice to.

Comment: If you really wanted to say that, and to a non-native student, wouldn't you prefer "As at the barber(s')…"?

Answer (score 0):

Just like at your barber, tipping a driver is always welcome.

Drivers welcome tips but don't require them, just like barbers.

Tipping -- never mandatory, always appreciated, by barbers as well as drivers.